# How do I add a drag up menu to my app (similar to the control center except it covers up the whole screen)?

Tags: ios, swift

The following code is meant to cause a view that is hidden below the main view to be able to be dragged from the bottom of the screen completely over the main view. For some reason, the code below does absolutely nothing. Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ControlMenuView: FXBlurView {

   var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!
   var container:UICollisionBehavior!
   var snap: UISnapBehavior!
   var dynamicItem: UIDynamicItemBehavior!
   var gravity:UIGravityBehavior!
   var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

   func setup () {
        panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ControlMenuView.handlePan(_:)))
        panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.superview!)
        dynamicItem = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [self])
        dynamicItem.allowsRotation = false
        dynamicItem.elasticity = 0

        gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self])
        gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, -1)

        container = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self])

        configureContainer()

        animator.addBehavior(gravity)
        animator.addBehavior(dynamicItem)
        animator.addBehavior(container)

    }

    func configureContainer (){
        let boundaryWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        container.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("upper", fromPoint: CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height), toPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryWidth, self.frame.size.height))

        let boundaryHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        container.addBoundaryWithIdentifier("lower", fromPoint: CGPointMake(0, boundaryHeight), toPoint: CGPointMake(boundaryWidth, boundaryHeight))


    }

    func handlePan (pan:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        let velocity = pan.velocityInView(self.superview).y

        var movement = self.frame
        movement.origin.x = 0
        movement.origin.y = movement.origin.y + (velocity * 0.05)

        if pan.state == .Ended {
            panGestureEnded()
        }else if pan.state == .Began {
            snapToTop()
        }else{
            animator.removeBehavior(snap)
            snap = UISnapBehavior(item: self, snapToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(movement), CGRectGetMidY(movement)))
            animator.addBehavior(snap)
        }

    }

    func panGestureEnded () {
        animator.removeBehavior(snap)

        let velocity = dynamicItem.linearVelocityForItem(self)

        if fabsf(Float(velocity.y)) > 250 {
            if velocity.y < 0 {
                snapToBottom()
            }else{
                snapToTop()
            }
        }else{
            if let superViewHeigt = self.superview?.bounds.size.height {
                if self.frame.origin.y > superViewHeigt / 2 {
                    snapToTop()
                }else{
                    snapToBottom()
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func snapToBottom() {
        gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, 2.5)
    }

    func snapToTop(){
        gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, -2.5)
    }
    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The following code is meant to cause a view that is hidden below the
>   main view to be able to be dragged from the bottom of the screen
>   completely over the main view.

You mention that the view is "hidden below the main view." Have you checked to see if the pan gesture target selector is even being called?

Comment: The view was intentionally placed below the screen initially so that isn't the problem if that is what you meant. Thanks for responding so quickly though!

Comment: I understand that, but you are adding the pan gesture recognizer to the view that is "hidden." I am just skeptical that the gesture recognizer is picking up the touch in the first place.